# Get value from C# lookup

Tags: c#-4.0, ienumerable, lookup

I'm interested in how to get value from C# lookup structure.

Example:

```
var myLookup = (Lookup<string, int>)data.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToLookup(row => row["Name"], row => row["Id"]);

foreach (var myLookupItem in myLookup)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Name: " + myLookupItem.Key);
                        Debug.WriteLine("Id: " + myLookupItem.ToString());
                    }
```

Problem is that the

```
myLookupItem.ToString()
```

doesn't display actual value, instead only `System.Linq.Lookup2[System.String,System.Int32]` is displayed.

Later on, I should get the lookup value using lambda:

```
 int lookupValue = myLookup.Where(x => x.Key == "Test").Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault());
```

but this also gives the same as above.

Please advise how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

That's because the lookup item is a collection. You can see every value of the lookup like this:

```
foreach (var myLookupItem in myLookup)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Key: " + myLookupItem.Key);
    foreach (var myLookupValue in myLookupItem)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Value: " + myLookupValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*"I do not think it means what you think it means."*

A Lookup ([from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx)):

> Represents a collection of keys each mapped to one or more values.

i.e. it groups them (*even if these groups are singular*).

It looks like you want to use something like a Dictionary instead of a Lookup.    In the case of a Dictionary.  You can use the ToDictionary() extension method instead of the ToLookup() extension method.  You'd then use key and value on the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

```
int lookupValue = myLookup.Where(x => x.Key == "Test").SelectMany(x => x).FirstOrDefault())
```

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer